# AdapterViewFlipper content of previous and present views intermix and abnormal width and height

Tags: android, xml

I am currently working on an android project that uses AdapterViewFlipper. The animation is working but the problem is that the texts in the textviews from previous and present views are intermixed as shown in the image.

[image]

Also I have been trying the whole day to make its width half the parent and its height to accommodate the whole content but no luck. I have googled a lot and could not find any concrete solutions.

Here is the declaration of AdapterViewFlipper:

```
<AdapterViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/dataFlipper"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"/>
```

and here is the layoutof AdapterViewFlipper item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEventName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalIncidents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalInjured"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalFamily"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalComplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalDeath"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalMissing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalEconomy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalPartial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help to resolve these problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have already found solution to my problem but forgot to mention here. In case someone faces the same problem, the solution is a single line code. It was in fact not the problem with adapter but with the fragments. Just adding the following line of code in the `onCreateView` method of the fragments solves the issue for me.

```
container.removeAllViews()
```